# How can I test what an AngularJS promise returns using Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, promise

I have the following code in a factory:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.factory('apiFactory', function($http) {
  return {
    'call':function(){
      $http.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(){
        return 'I visited Google!';
      });
    }
  };
});
```

And the following Jasmine test:

```
describe('Testing apiFactory', function() {
  var $scope,
  apiFactory,
  $http,
  $q,
  rootScope;

  beforeEach(module('plunker'));

  beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, _apiFactory_, _$http_, _$q_, _$rootScope_) {
    apiFactory = _apiFactory_;
    $http = _$http_;
    $q = _$q_;
    rootScope = _$rootScope_;
  }));

  it('should return "I visited Google!"', function(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    spyOn($http, 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
    deferred.resolve();
    apiFactory.call();
    rootScope.$apply();

    expect($http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://www.google.com');
  });
});
```

As you can see above, I know how to test the $http.get promise has been called but how can I test that the function passed to the `then()` methods returns ""I visited Google!"?

Here's a plunkr for this code: http://plnkr.co/edit/DrKGV11eTpi2CrtYtffp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, you just need to do a couple things.

1. In the apiFactory.call method, you should return $http.get(). This will return a promise to the caller.
2. You need to add some sort of check to verify that the result was returned from the apiFactory.call method.

I modified your test to look as follows:

```
it('should return "I visited Google!', function(){
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var result;

  spyOn($http, 'get').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
  deferred.resolve();

  apiFactory.call().then(function(resolved) {
    result = resolved;
  });

  expect($http.get).toHaveBeenCalledWith('http://www.google.com');
  expect(result).toBeUndefined();

  rootScope.$apply();

  expect(result).toBe('I visited Google!');
});
```

To clarify, your `apiFactory.call` method should look like the following:

```
return $http.get('http://www.google.com').then(function(){
  return 'I visited Google!';
});
```

This should work for you!

Comment: Right, you just call the `then()` method on the returned promise (BTW, I forgot to add the return in my example but I have it in my code) and check the parameters it was called with. I should have thought of that! Thanks a lot, great answer!